# custom base adapter don't work filter

Tags: android, android-adapter

i want set filter (search) in list view and use "extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable" for adapter class .

this my code :

```
public class UserList extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<Users> user;

    public UserList(Context context, List<Users> user) {
        this.context = context;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return user.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return user.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return user.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.listview_item, null);
        ImageView imgUser = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        TextView txtDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_short);
        TextView txtSex = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_sex);
        TextView txtAge = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_age);
        //get byte[] from db , resize and convert to bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(user.get(position).getPic(), 0, user.get(position).getPic().length);
        imgUser.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(bmp, 300, 150));
        txtName.setText(user.get(position).getUserName());
        txtDesc.setText(user.get(position).getUserDesc());
        txtSex.setText(user.get(position).getGender());
        txtAge.setText(user.get(position).getAge() + " ساله ");
        return view;
    }
```

and this my filter method :

```
private Filter filterResult = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Users> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint != null && user != null) {
                int length = user.size();
                int i = 0;
                while (i < length) {
                    Users item = user.get(i);
                    tempList.add(item);
                    i++;
                }
                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            user = (ArrayList<Users>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filterResult;
    }
```

but no happen when enter text for filter list view ... see this image :
[image]

Comment: user = (ArrayList<Users>) results.values;  problem is here u changing the reference

Comment: i don't know what doing !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few mistake in your code.

1. You must keep original array which did not have filter.
   You should change your code like this

   ```
   private List<Users> original;
   private List<Users> user;
   public UserList(Context context, List<Users> user) {
       this.context = context;
       this.user = user;
       this.original = user;
   }
   ```
2. You did not perform filter in your code. You need to correct your code

   ```
   @Override
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
       FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
       ArrayList<Users> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
       if (original != null) {
           if (TextUtil.isEmpty(constraint)){
               tempList = original;
           } else {
              int length = user.size();
              int i = 0;
              while (i < length) {
                 User item = original.get(i);
                 // check item again your constraint see example below
                 if (item.name.contain(constraint))
                     tempList.add(item);
                 i++;
              }
           }
       }
       filterResults.values = tempList;
       filterResults.count = tempList.size();
       return filterResults;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

in this case your dataset reference is changing on filter so adapter can not  getting reference to your data as per my solution i will do follow

declare temp list in adapter which contain all data

```
private List<Users> tempuser;
```

now fill this with looping to avoid reference problem and call it in adapter constructor

```
 private void fillData()
    {
   // initialize tempuserhere 
tempuser=new List<Users>() ; //check as per your model
         for(Users obj:user)
        {
          tempuser.add(obj);
         }

    }
```

in constructor

```
public UserList(Context context, List<Users> user) {
        this.context = context;
        this.user = user;
    fillData();
    }
```

now in filter process class

```
  @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && tempuser != null) {

                boolean fillAll=false;
                user.clear();
                if(constraint.toString().trim().length==0)
                   fillAll=true;
                for(Users objUser:tempuser)
                {
                  if(fillAll || constraint.toString().trim().toLowerCase().contains(objUser.value.toLowerCase()))///the objUser value replaced with your compare string
                  {
                     user.add(objUser);
                  }
                }
                filterResults.values = user;
                filterResults.count = user.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            user = (ArrayList<Users>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
```

you can try this if any problem let me know, also 
if any user know the standarad approach let me know

Comment: crash on method with null refrence :private void fillData()
    {
   // initialize tempuserhere
         for(Users obj:user)
        {
          tempuser.add(obj);
         }
    }

Comment: you have to initialize it  tempuser=new List<Users>() what before for loop in fillData check edit answer